# SQLite | Retreive data from two (schema) identical tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a `SQLite Database` where I fetch data from two tables with the following `query`.

```
select ie.* 
from (select * 
      from History where Station = @station and TimeStampCome <= @till and TimeStampCome >= @from 
      union all 
      select * 
      from Pending where Station = @station and TimeStampCome <= @till and TimeStampCome >= @from
     ) ie 
order by TimeStampCome desc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1
```

Is this the best and most performanced way? I have stored `alarm objects` in the `database`. So there can be easily more than 1 millions entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular query, it is probably better to limit the rows from each table first like this:

```
with h as (
      select h.*
      from history h
      where Station = @station and TimeStampCome <= @till and TimeStampCome >= @from 
      order by TimeStampCome desc
      limit 101
     ),
     p as (
      select p.*
      from pending p
      where Station = @station and TimeStampCome <= @till and TimeStampCome >= @from 
      order by TimeStampCome desc
      limit 101
     )
select pe.*
from (select h.* from h union all
      select p.* from p
     ) pe
order by TimeStampCome desc
limit 100 offset 1;
```

However, this becomes less feasible if you start working with different offsets.

Note that if performance is a concern, start with indexes on `(Station, TimeStampCome)` in both tables.

Comment: Ah this is a good hint `indexes`! I build the query depending on the submitted filters (station, from, till...) so this won't be such a problem.